# Layouting dynamic subviews in a UITableviewCell, make constrains to margins

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

In my app, I have a `UITableViewCell` which can contain an arbitrary `UIView` (or subclass hereof). I want the view to fit into the `UITableViewCell`'s `contentView`'s margins. And the cell height will be adjusted to the needs of my view.

I've tried various things but with no positive result.

Here's the code. It does not work. :(

It does not fit the margins and the content is wider than the screen size.

What to do?

```
class CustomView: UIStackView {
    class func viewFromNib() -> CustomView {
        guard let view = NSBundle(forClass: CustomView.self).loadNibNamed("CustomView", owner: nil, options: nil).first as? CustomView else {fatalError("CustomView not found")}
        return view
    }
}

class ViewController: UITableViewController {

    let customView = CustomView.viewFromNib()
    var containerCell: ContainerTableViewCell?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        containerCell = ContainerTableViewCell.cell(customView, height: nil)
        tableView.reloadData()
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 40
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        return containerCell ?? UITableViewCell()
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
}

class ContainerTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    var singleView: UIView?

    class func cell(view: UIView, height: CGFloat?) -> ContainerTableViewCell {
         let cell = ContainerTableViewCell()
        cell.setup(view, height: height)
        return cell
    }

    func setup(view: UIView, height: CGFloat?) {

        singleView = view
        contentView.addSubview(singleView!)

        let margins = contentView.layoutMarginsGuide
        singleView?.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(margins.topAnchor).active = true
        singleView?.leadingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(margins.leadingAnchor).active = true
        singleView?.trailingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(margins.trailingAnchor).active = true
        singleView?.bottomAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(margins.bottomAnchor).active = true
        setNeedsLayout()
        if let height = height {
            contentView.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(height).active = true
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should implement

```
optional func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat
```

in your `viewController` and to know the height of each cell when refreshing the table.

Answer (score 0):

`cellForRowAtIndexPath` **must** use a `dequeue` family method to get your table cell instance:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:

Such that the object will be created through its regular constructor, *not* your factory method. You don't have that flexibility.

So in your subclass, put your generic constraints in `awakeFromNib` or an overridden constructor. Don't forget to account for the auto-resizing mask which interferes with programmatic constraints, so this field must be set to `false`:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints

Finally, within the `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, you can modify the constraints of the `UITableViewCell` instance returned by the dequeue call, to get your custom height in there.

Good luck!